# Differences between instantiate as GameObject and instantiate as Transform

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I'm following video tutorials on Unity and the first teacher, that I had for the 2D part, always instantiate the bullets as GameObject while the second one, on the 3D part, always instantiate the bullets as Transform.

And the result seems to be the same but what are the differences? Is it just personal preferences?

Comment: You can refer to these documentations for knowing what is GameObject and Transform
GameObject - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.html
Transform - https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.html

Comment: Thanks @HardykMahendru but what is the purpose of instantiate as Transform and not as GameObject?

Comment: You have the transform reference, that's it. Actually, uou can get any type. If you have a prefab and you need MyType, then you can create a MyType reference and use MyType obj = Instantiate(myTypeRefence); the compiler will use the generic version with the return tyoe based on parameter type. In this case, it reduces the risk to drag a prefab that would not be right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider the `GameObject` as a place holder of different components and `Transform` is a specific component.

In the image below `GameObject` is the cube itself and in that cube we have attached different components like `Transform`, `Cube(Mesh Filter)` `Mesh Renderer` and `Box Collider`

So now in your case you can Instantiate by referencing the `GameObject` as a whole or its `Transform` component. Usually because people will possibly modify the `Transform` of the `GameObject` they will shorten the path a bit and directly Instantiate it by referring to its `Transform`. However it will be the same if you would Instantiate it as a `GameObject` only in that case if you want to modify the `Transform` of the object you would need to firstly access the component then modify it.

[image: Cube GameObject]

Comment: Thanks a lot! You were very clear and understandable. 

Answer (score 0):

There's not a significant difference, it's partially personal preference, and partially convenience if you are going to be referring to one more than the other.

It can mean less typing to use `Transform` if you'll be referring to the transform more, or use `GameObject` if you'll be referring to the gameobject more.